# except: invalid syntax after using actionChains

Tags: python, python-3.x

i get an error at this part of my code.

```
try:
    actionChains.double_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[4]/form/div/div").perform()

except NoSuchElementException:
    actionChains.double_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/div[2]/div").perform()
```

If I remove the second line of the code (`actionChains.double_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[4]/form/div/div").perform()`
), it works. But, if I don't It doesn't. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a clothing parenthesis in both `actionChains.double_click(...` lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add a closing parenthesis to the call to the `double_click` method:

```
try:
    actionChains.double_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[4]/form/div/div")).perform()

except NoSuchElementException:
    actionChains.double_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/div[2]/div")).perform()
```

Comment: Ooops. I guess I should be more careful. Thanks a lot !